# BRCS, BRNE and BRCC in assembly

Tags: assembly, avr

I have homework for assembly language, but I wanna do it by myself, but I have some difficulties with terminology. I have not found propper answer in google.
Can you explain with detail exaples the meaning of BRCS, BRNE and BRCC in assembly language?

Comment: You realize that "assembly language" exists for many different architectures, right? Please tag this question with the architecture you're asking about. Also, please explain what exactly, after reading the instruction set documentation, you don't understand about these instructions.

Comment: _"I have not found propper answer in google"_. _Really?_ The very first hit on google for _"avr BRCS"_ is the page in atmel's documentation for the `BRCS` instruction where they explain what it does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question you should ask google, not other people.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is tagged [avr] ... the three commands you mention belong to the "[minimal core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set#Instruction_set_inheritance)" of AVR 8 bit processors and are supported by all processors of that family.

Searching for "avr 8 bit instruction set" will quickly lead you to the relevant documents. The rest is your's ...

<[SPOILER](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)> only use in emergency

Answer (score 0):

It is probably AVR assembler, right?

BRCS is for "BRanch if Carry is Set",

BRCC -- "BRanch if Carry is Clear",

BRNE -- "BRanch if Not Equal" (or result is non-zero)

Comment: c'mon ... it's a homework ;-)

Comment: Well, yes for sure, but shouldn't I answer then if I like to answer? :)

Comment: hmmm yes ... and your answer of course is 100% correct

Comment: Answering bad questions encourages people to ask more bad questions, instead of learning how to google.  One school of thought here on SO is that we should refrain from answering bad questions.  Note that this is a bad question because the answer comes up easily on google, not because it's homework.  That has some bearing on how to answer a good question, but not on whether a question is good or bad.  Even trivial questions aren't always bad questions, IMO, if it's not obvious how to google them without already knowing the answer and correct terminology.  Not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know AVR, but 
BRCC sounds like "Branch if Carry Clear"  and 
BRCS like "Branch if Carry set" to me
while BCNE could be "Branch if Not Equal" 
The carry flag is usually a status register, used to determine overflows (like when you add 2 8bit values and the result doesnt fit into 8 bits) or shift operations (again 8 bit): if you shift left 0x81 once, the result will be 0x102, which doesn't fit into your 8 bit register, so the register will hold 0x02, and the carry will be set